# Check if matching object exist with id and manytomany field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have model as shown below :

```
class Product(AdcBaseModel):
    file_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    channels = models.ManyToManyField(Channel, blank=True)
```

While creating a new entry in this model, I wanted to check if entry already exist with the given file_id and channels.

For ex.
Suppose if I have entry in the Product as (Note:channels is ManytoMany field):

```
id      file_id         channels

1       ID_1            [11,12]
2       ID_2            [13,14]
2       ID_2            [15,16]
```

Now if again I enter the values iof file_id as ID_2 and channels as [15,16]. Then it should check if this entry already exist or not.

For file_id I can do something like this.:

```
Product.objects.filter(file_id="ID_2").exists()
```

Anything by which I can check ManytoMany field in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter on the through model which is created by django to form the M2M.

For example I've got this model with an M2M relationship;

```py
class Leaderboard(models.Model):
    """
    Leaderboard model
    """

    events = models.ManyToManyField(
        verbose_name=_('events'),
        to='entry.Event',
        related_name='leaderboards'
    )
```

On the `Event` model is a link to a `Client` model, so there is a case where we want to find the `Client` associated with a `Leaderboard` so the following query is used;

```py
    qs = leaderboard.events.through.objects.filter(
        leaderboard=leaderboard
    ).select_related(
        'event__client'
    )
```

So if you did `Product.channels.through.objects.filter()` you should be able to do the kind of filtering that you're familiar with. That `through` table would have 2 columns of `product_id` and `channel_id` for those FK relationships.